# Content going out from bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a page for my University website which only allows me to edit or create pages within the scope of a content management system. So basically, the template remains fixed within which I can insert my html code. So I created a responsive page using bootstrap but the content is going out of bound (without scrolling). I tried fixing the container width but didn't help. The page is working perfectly independently i.e when I run it as independent html file without the cms.
The nav works fine but the content in the container div doesn't.
Here is the link to the page:
[Boostrap Page in CMS](http://chicago.medicine.uic.edu/cms/One.aspx?portalId=506244&pageId=35058187)

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Home Page | Pediatrics Research | UIC College of Medicine | </title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <style>

    b, h3{
      color: #336699;
    }

      .navbar {
        background-color: rgb(31, 73, 125);
      }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li >a{
          color:white;
      }
      .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
        color: white;
      }
      .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover{
        color: white;
      }
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li >a:hover{
            color:white;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        @media (min-width: 767px) {
          .affix,.affix-top {
              position:fixed;
          }
        }

    .navbar-collapse ul{
    margin-left: 10%;
    }

    #sidebar  {

    background-color: lightgrey;
    }

    ul#sidebar {
    padding: 25px;
    }

    div#profile-right {
    border-left: solid 3px red;

    }

    </style>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">UIC Pediatrics</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Research</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Our Partners <span class="caret"></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Basic Research</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Clinical Trials</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Epidemiology Research</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Health Promotion Research</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Health System Redesign</a></li>
                  </ul></li>

            <li><a href="#">Work With Us</a></li>

          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" id="sidenav">
          <ul id="sidebar" class="nav nav-stacked">
            <li><a href="#">Our Researchers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pediatrics - 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pediatrics - 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pediatrics - 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pediatrics - 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pediatrics - 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        <h2>Marian L. Fitzgibbon, PhD </br> <small>Professor of Pediatrics and Health Policy and Administration</small></h2>
        <p><b>Contact Info</b></br>
        Phone: (312) 996-0146 </br>
        Fax: (312) 413-8950 </br>
        E-mail: <a href="mailto:mlf@uic.edu">mlf@uic.edu</a> </br>
        On Twitter: <a href="https://twitter.com/SBMPresident">@SBMPresident</a> </br>
        <b>Institute for Health Research and Policy</b> </br>
        University of Illinois at Chicago (MC 275) </br>
        486 Westside Research Office Bldg. </br>
        1747 West Roosevelt Road </br>
        Chicago, IL 60608
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <img src="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/files/mlf2015-150X200.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Marian L. Fitzgibbon, PhD" style="width=50px;height=70px"/>
      </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
          <h3>Profile</h3>
          <p>


          </p>
          <h3>Research Interests</h3>
          <p>

          </p>
          <h3>Recent and Noteworthy Publications</h3>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="profile-right">

        </div>
      </hr>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your code, especially regarding the container and content.

Comment: @mrkd1991 Just did that.

Comment: I see the image is squuezed.. do you want to fix that section?

Comment: use col-xs-12 instead of row in that section..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your .row has custom css added which is causing the problem

```
.row {
    width: 1060px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

So you **need to replace** this **class row** in the **content section**  with `col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12` . **Basically this class will give a 100% full width condition** .

> Updated your code.. Just add this code and it is good to go :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Home Page | Pediatrics Research | UIC College of Medicine | </title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <style>
    b,
    h3 {
      color: #336699;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      background-color: rgb(31, 73, 125);
    }
    
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 767px) {
      .affix,
      .affix-top {
        position: fixed;
      }
    }
    
    .navbar-collapse ul {
      margin-left: 10%;
    }
    
    #sidebar {
      background-color: lightgrey;
    }
    
    ul#sidebar {
      padding: 25px;
    }
    
    div#profile-right {
      border-left: solid 3px red;
    }
  </style>

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">UIC Pediatrics</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Research</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Our Partners <span class="caret"></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Basic Research</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Clinical Trials</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Epidemiology Research</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Health Promotion Research</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Health System Redesign</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li><a href="#">Work With Us</a></li>

        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" id="sidenav">
        <ul id="sidebar" class="nav nav-stacked">
          <li><a href="#">Our Researchers</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pediatrics - 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pediatrics - 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pediatrics - 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pediatrics - 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pediatrics - 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <!---removed row classs and added full width class col-*-12-->
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <h2>Marian L. Fitzgibbon, PhD </br> <small>Professor of Pediatrics and Health Policy and Administration</small></h2>
            <p><b>Contact Info</b></br>
              Phone: (312) 996-0146 </br>
              Fax: (312) 413-8950 </br>
              E-mail: <a href="mailto:mlf@uic.edu">mlf@uic.edu</a> </br>
              On Twitter: <a href="https://twitter.com/SBMPresident">@SBMPresident</a> </br>
              <b>Institute for Health Research and Policy</b> </br>
              University of Illinois at Chicago (MC 275) </br>
              486 Westside Research Office Bldg. </br>
              1747 West Roosevelt Road </br>
              Chicago, IL 60608
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <img src="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/files/mlf2015-150X200.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Marian L. Fitzgibbon, PhD" style="width=50px;height=70px" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <!---removed row classs and added full width class col-*-12-->
          <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <h3>Profile</h3>
            <p>


            </p>
            <h3>Research Interests</h3>
            <p>

            </p>
            <h3>Recent and Noteworthy Publications</h3>

          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="profile-right">

          </div>
          </hr>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Got it. Works now. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        b, h3 {
            color: #336699;
        }

        .navbar {
            background-color: rgb(31, 73, 125);
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav &amp;gt; li &amp;gt;a {
            color: white;
        }

        .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
            color: white;
        }

            .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
                color: white;
            }

        .navbar-default .navbar-nav &amp;gt; li &amp;gt;a:hover {
            color: white;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        @media (min-width: 767px) {
            .affix, .affix-top {
                position: fixed;
            }
        }

        .navbar-collapse ul {
            margin-left: 10%;
        }

        #sidebar {
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }

        ul#sidebar {
            padding: 25px;
        }

        div#profile-right {
            border-left: solid 3px red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">UIC Pediatrics</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Research</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle">Our Partners <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Basic Research</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Clinical Trials</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Epidemiology Research</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Health Promotion Research</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Health System Redesign</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Work With Us</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="sidenav" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
                <ul id="sidebar" class="nav nav-stacked">
                    <li><a href="#">Our Researchers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pediatrics - 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pediatrics - 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pediatrics - 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pediatrics - 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pediatrics - 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-9">
                <div class="row" style="overflow: hidden;">
                    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-8">
                        <h2>
                            Marian L. Fitzgibbon, PhD <br>
                            <small>Professor of Pediatrics and Health Policy and Administration</small>
                        </h2>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Contact Info</strong><br>
                            Phone: (312) 996-0146 <br>
                            Fax: (312) 413-8950 <br>
                            E-mail: <a href="mailto:mlf@uic.edu">mlf@uic.edu</a> <br>
                            On Twitter: <a href="https://twitter.com/SBMPresident">@SBMPresident</a> <br>
                            <strong>Institute for Health Research and Policy</strong> <br>
                            University of Illinois at Chicago (MC 275) <br>
                            486 Westside Research Office Bldg. <br>
                            1747 West Roosevelt Road <br>
                            Chicago, IL 60608
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4" style="text-align:center">
                        <img class="img-thumbnail" style="width=50px;height=70px" alt="Marian L. Fitzgibbon, PhD" src="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/files/mlf2015-150X200.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                        <h3>Profile</h3>
                        <p>
                            Dr. Fitzgibbon has focused primarily on health risk reduction interventions in minority and underserved populations. She has received consistent federal funding through NIH for more than a decade and regularly publishes in peer-reviewed journals. She serves as an ad hoc reviewer on a number of journals, including Health Psychology, The Journal of Consulting and Clinical Psychology, American Journal of Public Health, The Journal of The American Medical Association, and Ethnicity and Disease.
                            Dr. Fitzgibbon has mentored pre-doctoral, postdoctoral, and junior faculty for more than a decade. She has chaired 12 dissertation committees and is the primary mentor for two recipients of career development K awards through the National Cancer Institute (NCI). She recently received a minority supplement for a grant awarded from the NCI and is a mentor for a Career Development Awardee.
                            Dr. Fitzgibbon is a member of the <a href="#">NIH Behavioral Medicine: Interventions and Outcomes Study Section</a> and has served on a number of NIH Special Emphasis Panels. She is president-elect of the Society of Behavioral Medicine for 2014&ndash;2015 and chairs that organization's Health Policy Committee, and is recognized as a Fellow at the Institute for Health Research and Policy.
                        </p>
                        <h3>Research Interests</h3>
                        <p>
                            Dr. Fitzgibbon’s research focuses primarily on health risk reduction in minority and underserved populations. She has conducted obesity prevention trials with preschool children and their parents as well as obesity treatment interventions with women.
                        </p>
                        <h3>Recent and Noteworthy Publications</h3>
                        <p>For a more detailed list of publications by Dr. Marian Fitzgibbon, see <a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=fitzgibbon+ml">this edited list</a> on PubMed.</p>
                        <p>Hynes DM, Fischer MJ, Schiffer LA, Gallardo R, Chukwudozie IB, Porter A, Berbaum M, Earheart J, Fitzgibbon ML.&nbsp;Evaluating a novel health system intervention for chronic kidney disease care using the RE-AIM framework: Insights after two years.&nbsp;Contemp Clin Trials. 2016 Oct 18;52:20-26. [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/evaluating-novel-health-system-intervention-chronic-kidney-disease-care-using-re-aim">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Peterson CE, Khosla S, Chen LF, Joslin CE, Davis FG, Fitzgibbon ML, Freels S, Hoskins K. Racial differences in head and neck squamous cell carcinomas among non-Hispanic black and white males identified through the National Cancer Database (1998-2012). J Cancer Res Clin Oncol. 2016 Aug;142(8):1715-26. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27251759">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Buscemi J, Berlin KS, Rybak TM, Schiffer LA, Kong A, Stolley MR, Blumstein L, Odoms-Young A, Fitzgibbon ML. Health Behavior and Weight Changes Among Ethnic and Racial Minority Preschoolers and Their Parents: Associations Across 1 Year. J Pediatr Psychol. 2016 Aug;41(7):777-85. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26717958">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <div>Becker EA, Buscemi J, Fitzgibbon ML, Watson K, Matthews KL, Winn RA; Society of Behavioral Medicine Health Policy Committee. Society of Behavioral Medicine (SBM) position statement: SBM supports the National Colorectal Cancer Roundtable's (NCCRT) call to action to reach 80 % colorectal cancer screening rates by 2018. Transl Behav Med. 2016 Jun;6(2):306-8. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27357000">See statement.</a>]</div>
                        <div>&nbsp;</div>
                        <div>Kong A, Buscemi J, Stolley MR, Schiffer LA, Kim Y, Braunschweig CL, Gomez-Perez SL, Blumstein LB, Van Horn L, Dyer AR, Fitzgibbon ML. Hip-Hop to Health Jr. Randomized Effectiveness Trial: 1-Year Follow-up Results. Am J Prev Med. 2016 Feb;50(2):136-44. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26385162">See abstract.</a>]</div>
                        <p>Springfield S, Buscemi J, Fitzgibbon ML, Stolley MR, Zenk SN, Schiffer L, et al. A randomized pilot study of a community-based weight loss intervention for African-American women: Rationale and study design of Doing Me! Sisters Standing Together for a Healthy Mind and Body. Contemp Clin Trials. 2015 Jul;43:200-8. <a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/randomized-pilot-study-community-based-weight-loss-intervention-african-american-women">[See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Kong A, Vijayasiri G, Fitzgibbon ML, Schiffer LA, Campbell RT.&nbsp;Confirmatory factor analysis and measurement invariance of the child feeding questionnaire in low-income Hispanic and African-American mothers with preschool-age children. Appetite. 2015 Jul;90:16-22.&nbsp;[<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/confirmatory-factor-analysis-and-measurement-invariance-child-feeding-questionnaire-low">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Buscemi J, Blumstein L, Kong A, Stolley ML, Schiffer L, Odoms-Young A, Bittner C, Fitzgibbon ML.&nbsp;Retaining traditionally hard to reach participants: lessons learned from three childhood obesity studies. Contemp Clin Trials. 2015 Apr 3;42:98-104. [<a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25847577">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Buscemi J, Kanwischer K, Becker AB, Ward DS, Fitzgibbon ML.&nbsp;Society of behavioral medicine position statement: early care and education (ECE) policies can impact obesity prevention among preschool-aged children. Transl Behav Med. 2015 Mar;5(1):122-5. [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/early-care-and-education-policies-can-impact-obesity-prevention-among-preschool-aged">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Porter AC, Fitzgibbon ML, Fischer MJ, Gallardo R, Berbaum ML, Lash JP, Castillo S, Schiffer L, Sharp LK, Tulley J, Arruda JA, Hynes DM. Rationale and design of a patient-centered medical home intervention for patients with end-stage renal disease on hemodialysis.Contemp Clin Trials. 2015 Feb 28;42:1-8. [<a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25735489">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Peterson CE, Rauscher GH, Johnson TP, Kirschner CV, Freels S, Barrett RE, Kim S, Fitzgibbon ML, Joslin CE, Davis FG. The effect of neighborhood disadvantage on the racial disparity in ovarian cancer-specific survival in a large hospital-based study in cook county, Illinois. Front Public Health. 2015 Jan 22;3:8. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25657992">See abstract</a>.]</p>
                        <p>Buscemi J, Kong A, Fitzgibbon ML, Bustamante EE, Davis CL, Pate RR, Wilson DK. Society of behavioral medicine position statement: elementary school-based physical activity supports academic achievement. Transl Behav Med. 2014 Dec;4(4):436-8. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25584093">See abstract</a>.]</p>
                        <p>Buscemi J, Odoms-Young A, Stolley ML, Blumstein L, Schiffer L, Berbaum ML, McCaffrey J, Montoya AM, Braunschweig C, Fitzgibbon ML. Adaptation and dissemination of an evidence-based obesity prevention intervention: design of a comparative effectiveness trial. Contemp Clin Trials. 2014 Jul;38(2):355-60. [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/adaptation-and-dissemination-evidence-based-obesity-prevention-intervention-design">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Kong A,&nbsp;Odoms-Young AM, Schiffer LA,&nbsp;Kim Y,&nbsp;Berbaum ML, Porter SJ, Blumstein LB, Bess SL,&nbsp;Fitzgibbon ML. The 18-month impact of special supplemental nutrition program for women, infants, and children food package revisions on diets of recipient families.&nbsp;Am J Prev Med.&nbsp;2014 Jun;46(6):543-51. [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/18-month-impact-special-supplemental-nutrition-program-women-infants-and-children-food">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Peterson CE, Rauscher GH, Johnson TP, Kirschner CV, Barrett RE, Kim S, Fitzgibbon ML, Joslin CE, Davis FG.The association between neighborhood socioeconomic status and ovarian cancer tumor characteristics. Cancer Causes Control. 2014 May;25(5):633-7. [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/association-between-neighborhood-socioeconomic-status-and-ovarian-cancer-tumor-characteristi">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Smith-Ray RL, Fitzgibbon ML, Tussing-Humphreys L, Schiffer L, Shah A, Huber GM, Braunschweig C, Campbell RT, Hughes SL. Fit and Strong! Plus: design of a comparative effectiveness evaluation of a weight management program for older adults with osteoarthritis. Contemp Clin Trials. 2014 Mar;37(2):178-88. [<a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24316240">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Kong A, Jones BL, Fiese BH, Schiffer LA, Odoms-Young A, Kim Y, Bailey L, Fitzgibbon ML. Parent-child mealtime interactions in racially/ethnically diverse families with preschool-age children. Eat Behav. 2013 Dec;14(4):451-5. [<a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24183134">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Zenk SN, Powell LM, Odoms-Young AM, Krauss R, Fitzgibbon ML, Block D, Campbell RT. Impact of the revised Special Supplemental Nutrition Program for Women, Infants, and Children (WIC) food package policy on fruit and vegetable prices. J Acad Nutr Diet. 2014 Feb;114(2):288-96. [<a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24183996">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Odoms-Young AM, Kong A, Schiffer LA, Porter SJ, Blumstein L, Bess S, Berbaum ML, Fitzgibbon ML. Evaluating the initial impact of the revised Special Supplemental Nutrition Program for Women, Infants, and Children (WIC) food packages on dietary intake and home food availability in African-American and Hispanic families. Public Health Nutr. 2014 Jan;17(1):83-93. [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/evaluating-initial-impact-revised-special-supplemental-nutrition-program-women-infants-and-c">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Joo MJ, Sharp LK, Au DH, Lee TA, Fitzgibbon ML. Use of spirometry in the diagnosis of COPD: a qualitative study in primary care. COPD. 2013 Aug;10(4):444-9.&nbsp;[<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/use-spirometry-diagnosis-copd-qualitative-study-primary-care">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Fitzgibbon ML, Stolley MR, Schiffer L, Kong A, Braunschweig CL, Gomez-Perez SL, Odoms-Young A, Van Horn L, Kaufer Christoffel K, Dyer AR. Family-based Hip-Hop to Health: outcome results. Obesity (Silver Spring). 2013 Feb;21(2):274-83. [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/family-based-hip-hop-health-outcome-results">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Kong A, Odoms-Young AM, Schiffer LA, Berbaum ML, Porter SJ, Blumstein L, Fitzgibbon ML. Racial/ethnic differences in dietary intake among WIC families prior to food package revisions. J Nutr Educ Behav. 2013 Jan;45(1):39-46. [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/racialethnic-differences-dietary-intake-among-wic-families-prior-food-package-revisions">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Tussing-Humphreys LM, Fitzgibbon ML, Kong A, Odoms-Young A. Weight loss maintenance in African American women: a systematic review of the behavioral lifestyle intervention literature. J Obes. 2013;2013:437369. [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/weight-loss-maintenance-african-american-women-systematic-review-behavioral-lifestyle-interv">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Fitzgibbon ML, Tussing-Humphreys LM, Porter JS, Martin IK, Odoms-Young A, Sharp LK. Weight loss and African-American women: a systematic review of the behavioural weight loss intervention literature. Obes Rev. 2012 Mar;13(3):193-213. [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/weight-loss-and-african-american-women-systematic-review-behavioural-weight-loss-interventio">See abstract</a>.]</p>
                        <p>Nutescu EA, Bathija S, Sharp LK, Gerber BS, Schumock GT, Fitzgibbon ML. Anticoagulation patient self-monitoring in the United States: considerations for clinical practice adoption. Pharmacotherapy. 2011 Dec;31(12):1161-74. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22122179">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Joo MJ, Au DH, Fitzgibbon ML, McKell J, Lee TA. Determinants of spirometry use and accuracy of COPD diagnosis in primary care. J Gen Intern Med. 2011 Nov;26(11):1272-7.&nbsp; [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/determinants-spirometry-use-and-accuracy-copd-diagnosis-primary-care">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Fisher EB, Fitzgibbon ML, Glasgow RE, Haire-Joshu D, Hayman LL, Kaplan RM, Nanney MS, Ockene JK. Behavior matters. Am J Prev Med. 2011 May;40(5):e15-30. [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/behavior-matters">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Lown DA, Fitzgibbon ML, Dyer A, Schiffer L, Gomez S, Braunschweig CL. Effect of variable energy served on 24-hour energy intake in 16 preschools, Chicago, Illinois, 2007. Prev Chronic Dis. 2011 May;8(3):A58. [<a href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3103563/">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Fitzgibbon ML, Stolley MR, Schiffer LA, Braunschweig CL, Gomez SL, Van Horn L, Dyer AR. Hip-Hop to Health Jr. Obesity Prevention Effectiveness Trial: Postintervention Results. Obesity (Silver Spring). 2011 May;19(5):994-1003. [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/hip-hop-health-jr-obesity-prevention-effectiveness-trial-postintervention-results">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Fitzgibbon ML, Stolley MR, Schiffer L, Sharp LK, Singh V, Dyer A. Obesity Reduction Black Intervention Trial (ORBIT): 18-month results. Obesity (Silver Spring). 2010 Dec;18(12):2317-2325. [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/obesity-reduction-black-intervention-trial-orbit-18-month-results">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Joo MJ, Au DH, Fitzgibbon ML, Lee TA. Inhaled corticosteroids and risk of pneumonia in newly diagnosed COPD. Respir Med. 2010 Feb;104(2):246-52. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19879745">See abstract.</a>]&nbsp;</p>
                        <p>Fitzgibbon ML, Beech BM. The role of culture in the context of school-based BMI screening. Pediatrics. 2009 Sep;124 Suppl 1:S50-62. [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/role-culture-context-school-based-bmi-screening">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Gerber BS, Stolley MR, Thompson AL, Sharp LK, Fitzgibbon ML. Mobile phone text messaging to promote healthy behaviors and weight loss maintenance: a feasibility study. Health Informatics J. 2009 Mar;15(1):17-25. [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/mobile-phone-text-messaging-promote-healthy-behaviors-and-weight-loss-maintenance-feasibilit">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Stolley MR, Fitzgibbon ML, Schiffer L, Sharp LK, Singh V, Van Horn L, Dyer A. Obesity Reduction Black Intervention Trial (ORBIT): Six-month Results. Obesity (Silver Spring). 2009 Jan;17(1):100-6. [<a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/content/obesity-reduction-black-intervention-trial-orbit-six-month-results">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Lee TA, Au DS, Fitzgibbon ML, Weiss KB. Medication use patterns associated with spirometry in diagnosing COPD. COPD. 2008 Dec;5(6):360-368. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19353350">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Sharp LK, Fitzgibbon ML, Schiffer L. Recruitment of obese black women into a physical activity and nutrition intervention trial. J Phys Act Health. 2008 Nov;5(6):870-81. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19164821">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Pulvers KM, Kaur H, Nollen NL, Greiner KA, Befort CA, Hall S, Born W, Fitzgibbon ML, Ahluwalia JS. Comparison of body perceptions between obese primary care patients and physicians: implications for practice. Patient Educ Couns. 2008 Oct;73(1):73-81. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18583089">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Fitzgibbon ML, Stolley M, Schiffer L, Sharp L, Singh V, Van Horn L, Dyer A. Obesity Reduction Black Intervention Trial (ORBIT): design and baseline characteristics. J Womens Health (Larchmt). 2008 Sep;17(7):1099-110. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2944416/">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Fitzgibbon ML, Hayman LL, and Haire-Joshu D. Childhood obesity: can policy changes affect this epidemic? Society of Behavioral Medicine, July 2008. Available from: <a href="http://www.sbm.org/about/public-policy/statements/childhood-obesity">http://www.sbm.org/about/public-policy/statements/childhood-obesity</a></p>
                        <p>Banitt AA, Kaur H, Pulvers KM, Nollen NL, Ireland M, Fitzgibbon ML. BMI percentiles and body image discrepancy in black and white adolescents. Obesity. 2008 May;16(5): 987-991. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18292750">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Sanchez-Johnsen, L, Hogan K, Wilkens LR, Fitzgibbon ML. Correlates of problematic eating behaviors in less acculturated Latinas. Eat Behav. 2008 Apr;9(2):181-189. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18329596">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Fitzgibbon ML, Ferreira MR, Dolan NC, Davis TC, Rademaker AW, Wolf MS, Liu D, Gorby N, Schmitt BP, and Bennett CL. Process evaluation in an intervention designed to improve rates of colorectal cancer screening in a VA medical center. Health Promot Pract. 2007;8(3):273-281. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17606952">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Fitzgibbon ML, Gans KM, Evans WD, Viswanath K, Johnson-Taylor WL, Krebs-Smith SM, Rodgers AB, Yaroch AL. Communicating healthy eating: lessons learned and future directions. J Nutr Educ Behav. 2006;39:S63-S71. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17336811">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Fitzgibbon ML, Stolley MR, Schiffer L, Van Horn L, KauferKristoffel K, Dyer A. Hip-Hop to Health Jr. for Latino preschool children. Obes Res. 2006;14(9):1616-1625. [<a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17030973">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Fitzgibbon ML, Stolley MR. Commentary: Promoting health in an unhealthful environment: lifestyle challenges for children and adolescents. J Am Diet Assoc. 2006;106(4):518-522. [<a href="http://www.andjrnl.org/article/S0002-8223(06)00284-7/abstract">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                        <p>Nollen N, Kaur H, Pulvers K, Choi W, Fitzgibbon ML, Li C, Nazir N, Ahluwalia, JS. Correlates of ideal body size among Black and White adolescents. J Youth Adol. 2006;35(2):276-284. [<a href="http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10964-005-9024-3#/page-1">See abstract.</a>]</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="profile-right">
                        <p>
                            <strong>Other Title(s)</strong><br>
                            Deputy Director, IHRP; Associate Director, <a href="http://chicago.medicine.uic.edu/cms/One.aspx?portalId=506244&amp;pageId=5708129">UIC Cancer Center's Population Health, Behavior and Outcomes Program</a><br>
                            <br>
                            <strong>IHRP Affiliation(s)</strong><br>
                            <a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/center/center-health-behavior-research">Center for Health Behavior Research</a><br>
                            <br>
                            <strong>Current IHRP Research Studies (PI)</strong><br>
                            <a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/study/adaptation-and-dissemination-evidence-based-obesity-prevention-intervention">Adaptation and Dissemination of an Evidence-Based Obesity Prevention Intervention</a><br>
                            <a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/study/cancer-education-and-career-development-program-2013-2018">Cancer Education and Career Development Program</a><br>
                            <a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/study/comparative-effectiveness-customary-fit-and-strong-vs-fit-and-strong-plus">Comparative Effectiveness of Customary Fit and Strong! vs. Fit and Strong! Plus</a><br>
                            <a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/study/mediterranean-diet-weight-loss-and-cognition-obese-older-adults">Mediterranean Diet, Weight Loss, and Cognition in Obese Older Adults</a><br>
                            <br>
                            <strong>Current IHRP Research Studies (Co-I)</strong><br>
                            <a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/study/illinois-prevention-research-center-supporting-policy-and-environmental-change">Illinois Prevention Research Center (Illinois PRC): Supporting Policy &amp; Environmental Change</a><br>
                            <br>
                            <strong>Other Research (Non-IHRP)</strong><br>
                            Dissemination of a Weight Management Program among US Veterans (MOVE*VETS)<br>
                            Feasibility Study of Modified "Life Over Cancer" Intervention in Breast Cancer Patients<br>
                            Illinois Prevention Research Center<br>
                            Impact of a New WIC Food Package Fruit and Vegetable Cash-Voucher on Vendor Participation and Fruit and Vegetable Supply Characteristics
                            Weight Loss Maintenance in Black Women<br>
                            <br>
                            <strong>Recently Completed Research</strong><br>
                            <a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/study/adiposity-and-outcomes-clinically-localized-prostate-cancer">Adiposity and Outcomes of Clinically Localized Prostate Cancer</a><br>
                            <a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/study/center-excellence-eliminating-disparities">Center of Excellence in Eliminating Disparities</a><br>
                            <a href="http://www.ihrp.uic.edu/study/technology-based-measurement-home-food-availability-low-income-households">Technology-Based Measurement of Home Food Availability in Low-Income Households</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AnkurLathwal I change the code, see it again ,  now the content is not going out of bound
and you can change size of col , to achieve optimal arrangement